# SQL Server: Index and Include Columns

Tags: sql-server, nonclustered-index

Assume that I have a table Foo with columns A, B, C, D, and E. All are integers. Let's assume a million records, and that we're on SQL Server 2017.

The following index exists:

```
create Nonclustered index IX_Foo on Foo ([A], [B]) include ([C], [D], [E])
```

If I run the following query:

```
Select A, B, C, D, E from Foo where A = 1 and B = 2
```

Will this query trigger a Key Lookup in Foo because A and B are not included in the index's Include listing, or will SQL Server realize that A and B are located in the key itself and avoid a Key Lookup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A simple test with a little over 1M values**

**Data**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FOO([A] int , [B] int,[C] int, [D] int, [E] int);

INSERT INTO dbo.FOO([A]  , [B] ,[C] , [D] , [E] )
VALUES(1,1,1,1,1);
GO 1000

INSERT INTO dbo.FOO
SELECT * FROM dbo.FOO;
GO 10

INSERT INTO dbo.FOO([A]  , [B] ,[C] , [D] , [E] )
VALUES(1,2,1,1,1); --one matching record
```

*This dataset is not a real world dataset, as aside from one record, all the other records are the same.*

**Amount of rows**

```
select COUNT(*) from dbo.FOO
   (No column name)
1024001
```

**Query**

```
Select A, B, C, D, E from dbo.FOO where A = 1 and B = 2;
```

**No key lookup**

[image: In]

Which is normal as this index is perfect considering the query and the dataset.

**key column <> included column**

The main difference between the key columns and included columns is that 
these key columns are ordered [A] --> [B] (B-Tree) and the other columns [C], [D], [E] are not ordered (leaf level).

As a result seeking only on [A] is possible, seeking on [AB] is possible, but seeking only on [B] will create a residual predicate if the index is used.

[image]

Additionally

- You cannot add a column as both the key column and the included
  column
- Some datatypes cannot be added to the key column but could be included (all datatypes except `text`, `ntext`, and `image`)

  [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581294/index-key-column-vs-index-included-column)

---

**Example of a key lookup happening as a result of a different query**

```
create Nonclustered index IX_Foo_2 on dbo.FOO ([B]) include ([C], [D], [E]);

Select A, B, C, D, E from dbo.FOO where  B = 2;
```

A key lookup to get [A] happens, but it is not very expensive (one row).

[image]